# Cambiar el tipo de fuente solo en el titulo de la Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

Cordial saludo,
En mi archivo styles.xml he logrado cambiar el titulo de mi segunda actividad con title_activity_options, asi como el color de la barra:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#f40808</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff0101</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:text">@string/title_activity_options</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Lo que no he podido es cambiar ese tipo de fuente que tengo en assets\font\milton.ttf.

Alguien podria indicarme como hacerlo y en que parte se debe colocar el codigo sugerido.  Soy muy novato aun.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es lo mejor que he podido encontrar para ti, creo que es lo que estas buscando

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Title");
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "MyTypeface.otf"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(s);
```

[Esta](http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2013/03/styling-the-android-action-bar-with-a-custom-font/) es la web de donde lo he sacado